# Batch Insert from Repeater control using checkboxlist

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, webforms, batch-processing

I appreciate any insight where I am going wrong in this process. Pretty new at this and have been beating my head against a wall on this one. Probably something simple.

After searching to find examples, I am using a repeater that I have populated with a `SqlDataSource` and added a `checkboxlist` with static values that I am trying to get to insert into a Sql Server DB when a button is clicked from the repeater footer.  It is supposed to only insert from rows that have a value for the checkboxlist for users that have been assigned a task.

I am getting the following error

```
CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

If I comment out the if statement on the checkboxlist, the page will build without throwing an error, but the insert doesn't complete.

I have researched the error, but don't quite get what exactly I am doing wrong when checking the checkboxlist value in the if statement to select the rows with values.

Here is my code:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" runat="server" DataSourceID="TaskAssignReviewSDS">
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Users" />
        </FooterTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Width="400px">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="40%">
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="UserIdHidden" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("UserId") %>' />
                        <asp:Label ID="UserNamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="60%">
                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="AssignCB" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Assign</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Review</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

And related on click codebehind:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in Repeater3.Items)
        {

            CheckBoxList cb = ri.FindControl("AssignCB");
            if (cb.value != null)
            {
                string TasksId = Request.QueryString["TasksId"].ToString();
                string UserId = ((HiddenField)ri.FindControl("UserIdHidden")).Value;
                string Assignation = ((TextBox)ri.FindControl("AssignCB")).Text;
                //do inserting process using above values.


                string insertSql = "INSERT INTO TaskUser(UserId,TasksId, Assignation) VALUES(@UserId, @TasksID,@Assignation) ";

                using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source={*MyserverIP*}\\SQLEXPRESS12;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;User ID=****;Password=*****"))
                using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, myConnection))
                {
                    myConnection.Open();


                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TasksID", TasksId);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", UserId);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Assignation", Assignation);
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    myConnection.Close();
                }


            }

            }

    }
```

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: string Assignation = ((TextBox)ri.FindControl("AssignCB")).Text; is a problem, change that to reference to checkbox that might get you to your next error.

Comment: I'm also assuming that `if (cb.value != null)` should maybe just be `if (cb != null)`. Again, this may not solve your problem but they are a few things that should be looked at. Update your code if that helps so we can help you more with your problem...

Comment: Try using a radio button instead of a checkbox.

Comment: Seeing "Button1_Click" in the same code as a SqlConnection is making my eyes burn.

Comment: `granadaCoder`, can you give him an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `AssignCB` into a CheckBoxList. FindControl() just simply returns a `System.Web.UI.Control`.

```
CheckBoxList cb = (CheckBoxList)ri.FindControl("AssignCB");
```